# Fewer coding method to achieve the intended goal

Tags: c#

I have a set of buttons, the color of each button is Gray, and when I press any button, it changes its background color to SteelBlue and adjusts the colors of the other buttons to Gray, and to do that I rewrite the codes for each button, the question is there a short way to do this?
This is the code I used for each button:

```
private void btnFixing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnVibPanel.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnFixing.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    btnMReports.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnIdama.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnIdamaReports.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnWorkHours.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnWiqai.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnFixTable.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    btnUsers.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
}
```

Comment: Create a custom button and visualize it as you wish. [Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f5a10c/creating-custom-controls-in-C-Sharp/). Google for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If your buttons is on a panel or form, you can use a list to call all
> the buttons on that panel or form.

```
List<Button> btns = panelName.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
foreach(Button btn in btns)
{
    btn.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
}
```

> If your buttons can be found anywhere(on a panel, on a form) you can
> use an array to store all your buttons but you have to call every
> button.

```
Button[] btns = { btnVibPanel,  btnFixing, btnMReports, ....};
foreach(Button btn in btns)
{
    btn.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your buttons into a list:

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>
{
 btnVibPanel, btnFixing, btnMReports, ...
};
```

Then you can a use a loop to set the colour of all buttons to steel blue. The button that should be grey should have its colour changed after the loop:

```
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
   button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
}
btnFixing.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

If you want to avoid to use this code in all event handlers with only the button that should be grey changed, you can access the `sender` argument:

```
private void btnFixing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SwitchColors((Button)sender)
}

private void SwitchColors(Button grayButton)
{
    foreach(var button in buttons)
    {
       button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
    }
    grayButton.BackColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One slightly shorter way is:

```
btnVibPanel.BackColor = btnFixing.BackColor = btnMReports.BackColor = 
    btnIdama.BackColor = btnIdamaReports.BackColor = btnWorkHours.BackColor = 
    btnWiqai.BackColor = btnFixTable.BackColor = btnUsers.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
```

There are other ways such as "marking" the controls in some way (same name suffix, use a TAG, inherit from same Class, etc) and then iterating Controls to find and set the BackColor, but unless you need to do it often then it is probably not worth the effort!

If it is all controls of a certain type then you can of course iterate the controls, but I assumed you are only doing this for some.